# How can I change the names of the tables that are shown in brownie plugin menu (cakePhp)

Tags: cakephp, plugins, content-management-system

I am working with brownie plugin for cakephp and I would like to know if it is possible to change the names that the CMS show in the menu. By default it takes the name of the database tables, but I want to change the name only to display it in brownie, no modify the table name.

Is any configuration in $brwConfig that changes the name, something like

'fields' => array(
            'names' => array('name'=>'new name'),
        ),

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't look like that is the case.  Looking at the [app_controller for the project](http://codaset.com/plusglobal/browniephp/source/master/blob/brownie_app_controller.php), the _menuConfig() function doesn't reference any external configurations when it creates the menu.

If you really want changes, you'd have to modify the plugin to my understanding - there is no way to override specific functions from your main app.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yeah I saw it, well will check if I really want to modify it. Also I wonder if you know how autopopulate some fields of the data base, for example createdAT with the actual date?? thanks, Cesar